# How to show a pp_response variable on cs-cart front end?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I'm integration a custom payment method on cs cart. After the payment is complete I need to display to the user the transaction ID but I do not know how to rescue it.
I'm saving the trasancition ID in the payment procesor file and adding the variable name to the $pp_response array file, like this:

```
$pp_response["transaction_id"] = $tbk_auth;
```

I know this is working becouse in the orders details in admin panel the Trasacion ID is displaying correctly.

The question is: How to display transacction ID to the customer? How Can I access the $pp_response array to get this info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is in the $pp_response array, you can create a hook file in

```
/skins/[your_skin]/customer/addons/my_changes/hooks/orders/totals.pre.tpl
```

(modify the file name to indicate where you want it to show up)

Then in the file, you can access it by using

```
{$order_info.payment_info.transaction_id}
```

This will add to the table at the bottom of the page by the order totals. You can change the file name to put your info wherever there's a TPL hook.

This is an example from my custom payment processor response:

```
<tr>
  <td>Card Type</td>
  <td>{$order_info.payment_info.cardType}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps.